# Relationship between Frobenius reciprocity, Frobenius algebras, Frobenius extensions and Frobenius functors

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let me start by explaining what I mean by the terms in the question. Let $\Bbbk$ be a fixed field (for the sake of simplicity). As far as I know

1. Frobenius reciprocity says that for $H$ a subgroup of $G$, the induction functor $\mathsf{Ind}_H^G$ is left adjoint to the restriction functor $\mathsf{Res}^G_H$. This can be seen as an immediate consequence of the hom-tensor relation, since
   $$
   \mathsf{Hom}_{\Bbbk G}(\Bbbk G\otimes_{\Bbbk H} V,U)
   \cong\mathsf{Hom}_{\Bbbk H}(V,\mathsf{Hom}_{\Bbbk G}(\Bbbk G,U)).
   $$
2. A Frobenius algebra is a $\Bbbk$-algebra $A$ such that $A\cong \mathsf{Hom}_\Bbbk(A,\Bbbk)$ as regular left (equiv. right) $A$-modules.
3. An extension of $\Bbbk$-algebras $R\to S$ is Frobenius if and only if there exists an $R$-bilinear morphism $\epsilon:S\to R$ and (a finite number of) elements $x_i,y_i\in S$ such that
   $$\sum_ix_i\epsilon(y_is) = s = \sum_i\epsilon(sx_i)y_i$$
   for all $s\in S$.
4. A pair of functors $\mathcal{F}:\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}$, $\mathcal{G}:\mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{C}$ is Frobenius if $\mathcal{G}$ is at the same time left and right adjoint to $\mathcal{F}$.

Now, one can show that an extension $R\to S$ is Frobenius if and only if the restriction of scalars functor $\mathsf{Hom}_S(S,-)$ is Frobenius. A $\Bbbk$-algebra is Frobenius if and only if the extension $\Bbbk \to A$ is Frobenius.
What is not clear to me at the present moment is:

> **Question**: How are the last three notions realted with the Frobenius reciprocity?

For example, I have been told that the fact that $\Bbbk G$ is Frobenius for a finite group $G$ is essentially the Frobenius reciprocity, but at the present moment I don't see the connection.

Comment: "I have been told that the fact that $\Bbbk G$ is Frobenius for a finite group $G$ is essentially the Frobenius reciprocity" It is, but only if you define the induction as coinduction (i.e., via Hom rather than via tensor).

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm sorry, I didn't understand your comment. Do you mean that if I define the induction functor from $\Bbbk H$-modules to $\Bbbk G$-modules as $\mathsf{Hom}_{\Bbbk H}(\Bbbk G,-)$ by using the natural $\Bbbk H$-module structure on $\Bbbk G$, then the fact that $\Bbbk G$ is _Frobenius over $\Bbbk$_ tells me that $\mathsf{Hom}_{\Bbbk H}(\Bbbk G,-)$ is left adjoint to $\Bbbk G \otimes_{\Bbbk G} -$? Could you detail a bit more, please?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm claiming. But I don't know of a good reference. By all reason, this should be somewhere in Martin Lorenz's *A Tour of Representation Theory*, ideally in the form of "if $A \to B$ is [a Frobenius ring extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_algebra#Generalization:_Frobenius_extension), then induction $\operatorname{Ind}_B^A$ and coinduction $\operatorname{Coind}_B^A$ are isomorphic as functors". I don't know the details, though, as I've only ever done it for groups and subgroups.

Comment: Ah: See page 1 of [Kiiti Morita, *Adjoint pairs of functors and Frobenius extensions*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/050e/9414a47ad1f21653acb829f1b71758d60492.pdf). Note that $\operatorname{Ind}_B^A \cong \operatorname{Coind}_B^A$ is equivalent to $\left(\operatorname{Ind}_B^A, \operatorname{Res}_B^A\right)$ being a strongly adjoint pair, since the right adjoint of $\operatorname{Res}_B^A$ is always $\operatorname{Coind}_B^A$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg thanks for the reference. OT: actually, Morita's paper is my favourite paper on the topic. BTW, I'm sorry but I am afraid I didn't explain myself: if $\Bbbk G$ is a Frobenius extension of $\Bbbk H$, then I agree and it is clear to me how it works. But if I only know that $\Bbbk G$ is Frobenius over $\Bbbk$, is this enough to claim that it is also Frobenius over $\Bbbk H$? As far as I can see, if $\Bbbk G$ is Frobenius over $\Bbbk$ it means that $char(\Bbbk)$ does not divide $|G|$ and hence also $\Bbbk H$ is Frobenius over $\Bbbk$, but what about $\Bbbk G$ over $\Bbbk H$?

Comment: Ah, I interpreted your question less precisely than it was meant. I don't know right off the bat whether absolute Frobenity implies relative Frobenity. Sorry.

Comment: @darijgrinberg don't worry, thanks for your effort. Let's see if somebody else comes out with a solution.